# Flutter package http/http.dart target of URI doesn't eixst

Tags: flutter, http, dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

I encountered this problem!

I added the package to `pubspec.yaml` file and run `flutter pub get` (also have tried `flutter clean`) but when importing in vscode it gives me a notification.

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:http/http.dart'. Try creating file reference by URI, or Try using URI for a file that  doesn't exist. dart(URI doesn't exist)

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try restarting the IDE

Comment: If it didn't work, try removing the http dependency from pubspec.yaml and run `flutter pub add http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I fixed this problem. I have restarted the IDE but it still doesn't work. So I tried restarting my computer and reopening the terminal with `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. After that, the error message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using *package:http/http.dart*, you can use *dio* package, by adding *dio: ^4.0.0* to ***pubspec.yaml file***. *dio* only requires a String url.